# Подскажите компонент для Delphi XE2, который выделяет диапазон значений

Tags: delphi, компоненты

Подскажите компонент для Delphi XE2, который выделяет диапазон значений.

Есть TrackBar, но он используется для выбора определённого числа. Нужно нечто подобное.

[Пример](http://likbezz.ru/_example/jquery/ui_slider/ui_slider_2.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У TMS есть компонент TAdvTrackBar. Нужный вам - по центру картинки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]